# How to insert a model view with 5 string parameters into one input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC and I must insert a model view with 5 string parameters into one input(type text, or instead of input it will work textarea) with decent looks (like every parameter value on a separate row). The problem is that I'm not alowed to use html helpers. Any idea? It's a response after I get all properties from previous page. So this form including the input is method="get"

model view it's like:

```
class phonebook
{
  firstname {get;set;}
  lastname {get;set;}
  ...
}

phonebook el;
```

and it must be something like:

```
<input type="text" value="@el"/>
```

I know this isn't correct, but that's the idea

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show us your code (real code).

Comment: What will you do after input value changed? If you want to post back data for doing some thing in the same class model... forget it

Answer (score 0):

I have no IDE right now but from memory:

```
@model AspTest.phonebook

<textarea type="text" name="allinone">@(String.Join("\r\n", Model.firstname, Model.lastname))</textarea>
```

Comment: It must be all properties in just one input.

Comment: @AndreiB edited my previous answer - now it's all in single textarea

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<input value='@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(phonebook))'/>
```

Comment: Ok then remove the Html.Raw